# Why can't I remove new jQuery created li?

Tags: jquery, web

I am trying to create a User Interface List that utilities jQuery formatting. Users add to the list w/ an input field and an add button, and can sort their list using the sortable capabilities, and SHOULD be able to double click to remove items from their list. However, the double click remove only works on the original ol li items i had entered in my html for example. The li objects I added in the jQuery are not being removed by the double click for some reason. Does anyone know why?

Code Excerpt Below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ol').sortable();
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
        $('.list').append('<li>' + toAdd + '</div>');
    });
    $("li").dblclick(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $(document).on('.dblclick', 'li', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: OMG is that code/indentation style hard to read. *Edit: Looks like someone decided to change it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there are two problems (solved below, with a live example):

This code:

```
$("li").dblclick(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

...will only hook up the `dblclick` event on elements that exist when it runs. So it doesn't hook it up on elements you add later.

This code:

```
$(document).on('.dblclick', 'li', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

...*tries* to handle it via event delegation, but you shouldn't have that leading `.` on `.dblclick`.

So (using a more normal code/indentation style):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ol').sortable();

    $('#button').click(function () {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();

        $('.list').append('<li>' + toAdd + '</div>');
    });

    $(document).on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ewocih/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ewocih/1/edit)

What I did there was remove the first item I mentioned above, since it won't work for dynamically-added elements, and fixed the second one (removed the `.`).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".list").on('dblclick', 'li',function () {  
   $(this).remove();
});
```